# pdf generation of final output of jsp in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

i am working a small bus application in spring mvc after selecting bus seat click on continue it shows the ticket details and passinger details ,in this page am having a link  **VIEWPDF**
and clicking on that link I want that the above output becomes in pdf format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html2canvas for generate pdf for existing jsp. For more information go through the link  http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/?p=304